# Trying to read a file of tab-delimited strings and put them into an array and output, but I am only getting one character?

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I generated a simple tab-delimited file that is of the following format:

```
a    aa    aaa
b    bb    bbb
...
...
y    yy    yyy
z    zz    zzz
```

I am trying to read the file line-by-line, and put the strings into an array of strings, and then output the contents of the array of strings. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int BUF = 1024;
    FILE  * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    fp = fopen("~/testdataStrings.txt", "r") ;
    ssize_t read;


    char n[BUF] ;
    int offset,index = 0 ;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char* array[3] ;
        index = 0 ;
        while ( 1 == sscanf(line, "%s%n[^\n]", n, &offset) ) {
            // printf("%s\n", n) ; //n contains the proper value, a,aa,or aaa
            array[index] = n ; 
            line += offset ;
            index++ ;
        }


        int i = 0;
        while(i < 3) {
             printf("%s\n", array[i]) ;
             i++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is: a,aa,aaa,b,bb,bbb etc. separated by newlines, but I am getting: aaa,aaa,aaa,bbb,bbb,bbb etc separated by newlines? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `char* array[3]` declares array of pointers to char and not array of string. So either allocate them dynamically or declare something similar to `char array[3][BUF]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array[index] = n ;
```

is pointing to the `n` buffer. All the array element will point to same buffer `n`. and `n` will keep the last string read by the `sscanf()`

So you have to create a duplicated memory of `n` buffer each time you fill the `n` buffer with the `sscanf()`

So change

```
array[index] = n ;
```

to

```
array[index] = strdup(n) ;
```